# How do you configure the master priority register for i.MX21 in vanilla kernel 3.0.x?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm

I am running Linux kernel 3.0.x on my iMX21 device and by using imxfb I can display my graphics however when doing other tasks the screen will flicker and eventually stop working.
From what I have read on-line this is fixed by doing the following to kernel 2.6.16:

Slave port for EMI - LCD/SLCD highest priority, ARM lowest
MAX_MPR(3) = 0x00123056;

I am unsure how to do this in my version of kernel.